# Contar valores en un vector fila de un dataframe

Tags: array, r

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema. Si tengo un dataframe que posee varias columnas (variables). Y quiero anexar una nueva variable que CUENTE el "numero" de veces la ocurrencia de un valor o texto en dicho vector fila.

Es decir:

```
     columna1 columna2 columna3 columna4 numero
1       Sí       Sí       No       Sí      3
2       No       No       No       Sí      1
3       Sí       Sí       No       Sí      3
4       Sí       Sí       No       Sí      3
5       No       Sí       No       Sí      2
6       Sí       Sí       No       Sí      3
7       Sí       Sí       No       Sí      3
8       No       Sí       Sí       No      2
```

Quiero agregar la columna "numero", que cuente el numero de "Sí" en cada fila.En R he contado cantidades de veces por filas pero no por columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, suponiendo que tu `data.frame`  se llama `df`:

```
df$numero <- apply(df, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) sum(x=="Sí"))
```

"Aplicamos" con `apply()` a cada fila (`MARGIN=1`), la suma de los valores iguales a `Sí`, el resultado es un vector de lógicos que se coercionan en 1 = `TRUE` y 0  = `FALSE` al sumar.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. Funciona!